# Issue when trying to load 6 values into 7 fields with auto increment

Tags: php, mysql

I tried to do an INSERT to the database and i got this error:

Column count doesn't match value count at row 1.

```
<?php

//abm.php
    public function __construct($nombre_tabla){
        $this->conexion = new mysqli("localhost","root","","prueba");
        $this->nombre_tabla = $nombre_tabla;
    }

    public function setCampos($campos){
        $this->campos = $campos;
    }

    public function setValores($valores){
        $this->valores = $valores;
    }

    public function insertar(){
        $sql = "INSERT INTO $this->nombre_tabla($this->campos) VALUES($this->valores)";
        $this->conexion->query($sql);
    }
?>
```

```
<?php

$rol_usuario = $_GET['rol_usuario'];
$nombre = $_GET['nombre'];
$apellido = $_GET['apellido'];
$correo = $_GET['correo'];
$clave = $_GET['clave'];
$dni = $_GET['dni'];

include 'abm.php';

$tabla = new Tabla_mysql("usuarios");
$tabla->setCampos("rol_usuario,nombre,apellido,correo,clave,dni");
$tabla->setValores($rol_usuario,$nombre,$apellido,$correo,$clave,$dni);
$tabla->insertar();

?>
```

I understand that this happens because the amount of values is lesser than the amount of fields in the database. In the database there are 7 fields and i need to load 6 values. I loaded 6 because the field "id_usuario" is an AUTO INCREMENT.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `usuarios`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!50503 SET character_set_client = utf8mb4 */;
CREATE TABLE `usuarios` (
  `id_usuario` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `rol_usuario` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `nombre` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `apellido` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `correo` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `clave` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dni` varchar(8) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_usuario`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_general_ci;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
```

This issue only happens when i try to load from a form, but if i hardcode, it works without any problem.

Comment: I need that id_usuario be incremental.

Comment: I understand what you said, but i don't know how to do it.

Comment: An alternative way: Set the auto_increment field to have value of NULL

Comment: I added "id_usuario" on "CAMPOS" and NULL in "VALORES", but the error persists $tabla->setCampos("id_usuario,rol_usuario,nombre,apellido,correo,clave,dni"); $tabla->setValores(NULL,$rol_usuario,$nombre,$apellido,$correo,$clave,$dni); public function insertar(){ $sql = "INSERT INTO $this->nombre_tabla($this->campos) VALUES($this->valores)"; $this->conexion->query($sql }

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

Name only the columns you want. If you exclude the auto-increment column, it defaults to generate a new auto value.

```
INSERT INTO usuarios (rol_usuario,nombre,apellido,correo,clave,dni) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

Default to all the columns, but pass NULL for the auto-increment column. This activates the auto-increment feature to generate a new auto value.

```
INSERT INTO usuarios VALUES (NULL, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/example-auto-increment.html says:

> If the column is declared NOT NULL, it is also possible to assign NULL to the column to generate sequence numbers. For example:
>
> ```
> INSERT INTO animals (id,name) VALUES(NULL,'squirrel');
> ```

Comment: I added "id_usuario" on "CAMPOS" and NULL in  "VALORES", but the error persists

$tabla->setCampos("id_usuario,rol_usuario,nombre,apellido,correo,clave,dni");

$tabla->setValores(NULL,$rol_usuario,$nombre,$apellido,$correo,$clave,$dni);


public function insertar(){
        $sql = "INSERT INTO $this->nombre_tabla($this->campos) VALUES($this->valores)";
        $this->conexion->query($sql
}

Comment: Then I would infer that the table does not have seven columns.

Comment: Can you log the final query? It's easier to troubleshoot by looking at the SQL after it has been formatted, instead of looking at the code that supposedly formats SQL.

Comment: I managed to correct the error: $tabla->setCampos("id_usuario,rol_usuario,nombre,apellido,correo,clave,dni");
$tabla->setValores("'','$rol_usuario','$nombre','$apellido','$correo','$clave','$dni'");